# Extending Linux file system after resizing the EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, software-raid, amazon-ebs

I have resized the EBS volume using the AWS console Modify Volume. This is what the lsblk command returns before any change:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
xvdn    202:208   0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdc    202:32    0   80G  0 disk  
└─md1     9:1     0  160G  0 raid0 /mnt/temp
xvda    202:0     0    8G  0 disk  
└─xvda1 202:1     0    8G  0 part  /
xvdp    202:240   0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdo    202:224   0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdb    202:16    0   80G  0 disk  
└─md1     9:1     0  160G  0 raid0 /mnt/temp
xvdq    202:4096  0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
```

I have increased the size of xvdn(/dev/sdn) to 6G. After which I restarted the instance. Note xvdn is used to create a RAID 0 array of 4 devices.

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
/dev/xvda:  DOS/MBR boot sector; GRand Unified Bootloader, stage1 version 0x3, stage2 address 0x2000, 1st sector stage2 0x800, stage2 segment 0x200, GRUB version 0.94, extended partition table (last)
/dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=1afa51d9-105a-4c14-8f32-8b8b424b1c81 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/xvdb:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=cbe5ee82:c33cad21:699bec71:b4cf4a63 name=dbx_head:head_ephem level=0 disks=2
/dev/xvdc:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=cbe5ee82:c33cad21:699bec71:b4cf4a63 name=dbx_head:head_ephem level=0 disks=2
/dev/xvdn:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=c42b27c0:3586d4c5:635e2925:39a006e5 name=dbx_head:head_ebs level=0 disks=4
/dev/xvdo:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=c42b27c0:3586d4c5:635e2925:39a006e5 name=dbx_head:head_ebs level=0 disks=4
/dev/xvdp:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=c42b27c0:3586d4c5:635e2925:39a006e5 name=dbx_head:head_ebs level=0 disks=4
/dev/xvdq:  Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=c42b27c0:3586d4c5:635e2925:39a006e5 name=dbx_head:head_ebs level=0 disks=4
```

Which is mounted on `xfs` file type:

```
$ mount
/dev/md0 on /mnt/data type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,swalloc,attr2,largeio,inode64,logbsize=128k,sunit=256,swidth=1024,noquota)
/dev/md1 on /mnt/temp type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,swalloc,attr2,largeio,inode64,sunit=256,swidth=512,noquota)
/dev/md0 on /xdlog type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,swalloc,attr2,largeio,inode64,logbsize=128k,sunit=256,swidth=1024,noquota)
```

After restarting there's no change in the size, so I did

```
$ xfs_growfs -d /dev/md0
meta-data=/dev/md0               isize=2048   agcount=17, agsize=262112 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=4194176, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=32     swidth=128 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=32 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

Now, the `lsblk` returns:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
xvdn    202:208   0    6G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdc    202:32    0   80G  0 disk  
└─md1     9:1     0  160G  0 raid0 /mnt/temp
xvda    202:0     0    8G  0 disk  
└─xvda1 202:1     0    8G  0 part  /
xvdp    202:240   0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdo    202:224   0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
xvdb    202:16    0   80G  0 disk  
└─md1     9:1     0  160G  0 raid0 /mnt/temp
xvdq    202:4096  0    4G  0 disk  
└─md0     9:0     0   16G  0 raid0 /mnt/data
```

But when I the file size through `df -h`, it shows no change:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.4G   96K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.4G   55M  7.3G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.8G  6.0G  23% /
tmpfs           7.4G   24K  7.4G   1% /home/xdaux/tmp
tmpfs           7.4G  124K  7.4G   1% /home/xdcrm/tmp
/dev/md0         16G   35M   16G   1% /xdlog
/dev/md1        160G  3.1G  157G   2% /mnt/temp
```

What am I doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xvdn` is part of a RAID0 array (`md0`), which is used by the filesystem. To extend the filesystem, you need to extend the `md0` array but this requires you to extend **all four** component devices first. Basically:

- take an EBS volume snapshot and/or other backups. Do ***NOT*** skip this step!
- resize *all* four devices
- umount the filesystem (`umount /dev/md0`)
- stop the array (`mdadm -S /dev/md0`)
- re-assemble the array with the `--update=devicesize` option (`mdadm --assemble --update=devicesize /dev/md0 /dev/xvdn /dev/xvdp /dev/xvdo /dev/xvdq`)
- remount the filesystem (`mount /dev/md0 /xdlog`)
- grow the filesystem (`xfs_growfs /dev/md0`)

Please note that I posted the bash commands for convenience only, please *triple check* before doing destructive operations.

Comment: It's working  like charm.